# Looking for the title of a 70s/80s SCIFi book about an invasion of human space by either AI or Aliens

Tags: story-identification

I recall minor details about the story, I recall the enemy AI using flechette as weapons ( i know, very common).  I recall the story involving one of the protagonist that had an Al' or T' before his last name being the hereditary leader or something that would allow him to convince the AI of a lost fleet of ships to help fight the invasion.

Comment: Please take a look at the [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it jogs your memory to add any useful details - as they're a bit sparse at present.

Comment: Activating a robotic fleet of millions of ancient AI-controlled ships is the plot device used by the Space Angel’s crew to briefly distract their enemy in “Space Angel” by John Maddox Roberts (1979).